# apt-get --simulate dist-upgrade without notice

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt-get, deb

I want to do simulation of dist-upgrade without notice about simulation:

> NOTE: This is only a simulation!
>         apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
>         Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
>         so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!

I found that there is some option that turned on by default: "APT::Get::Show-User-Simulation-Note". I want turn it off by adding option:

```
--no-show-user-simulation-note
```

But in this case I got error message:

> Command line option --no-show-user-simulation-note is not understood

How can I manage this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `apt-get -o=APT::Get::Show-User-Simulation-Note=no --simulate ...`